# running multiple test case in Selenium at the same time

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I created 2 test suites with Selenium IDE and I would like to run those test suites at the same time. Just  like  firing threads at the same time. Is it possible without entering programming ?

P.S : I couldn't open 2 selenium IDE in Firefox.

Thanks.

Altug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not possible. Selenium IDE takes over the firefox control. And this is similar to 2 users clicking into same window.

The rule is 1 Firefox = 1 Selenium IDE

For parallel run you can setup [Selenium grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2). But it's more complicated solution than Selenium IDE.

Comment: grid is overkill. Use multiple profiles of firefox.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, you have to run multiple profiles of the Firefox browser. You can do it by command

```
firefox -p Profile_Name -no-remote
```

make use of profile manager if you need:

```
firefox -profilemanager -no-remote
```

You can run as many profiles simultaneously you want... or your memory can handle. For each profile you have to install Selenium addons separatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/)